# Post request getting data of database mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, guzzle

I have a database in MYSQL where one of the fields tells the status of a particular transaction. For example: `status = waiting` or `status = complete`.

I want to do a cron that every 10 minutes takes all clients that are with `status=complete` and I want to post the returned data to another URL, I'll use the same data in another application. I'm going to use Guzzle to send this data, but I still do not know how to make the request.

I think that can do this with foreach, but in some tests here it did not work!

Comment: If possible, I think it would be better to call the other url once with all your clients (status complete), than N times because it will do a lot of call in a short time to the other url.
(I mean N is the number of client with status complete).

Comment: But, the other clients can change the atual status in database and other clients can be registered in my database

Comment: Ok, what I meant was: make only one call every 10 minutes with all the client and not n calls (one call/client) every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.connections.php

```
<?php
try {

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        // your Guzzle request here
    }
    $dbh = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: I will try do it

Comment: It Works for me